# How to fix -> Clearing orphaned inode [number]

Tags: boot, 18.04, system-installation

So this happened.

I wasn't doing anything on my laptop . I turned it off and turned it back on again . A black screen with "Clearing orphaned inode" and then takes me to a screen where it asks me to put my root password or press ctrl+D. I tried my ubuntu password and I am sure I insert it correctly but it says it's wrong .

What are my options ?

Also, I tried reinstalling ubuntu ... which is not ideal ... but hey ... and when I select the booting devices and insert my bootable drive press ESC and F9 the usb doesn't show up (only the installed OS and the UEFI something).

My laptop is a dell da0135nq and the Ubuntu is LTS 18.04

Comment: that is not my issue.  I couldn't care less about the sudo password. I can reset it once I'm in. the screen is stuck at "insert root password for maintenance or Ctrl+d" to continue . My question is what's this error and how can i fix it given that I don't seem to use the right root password

Comment: In my case it was just a matter of switching off the laptop.  A reboot appeared to start the OS cleanly again.  If the problem persists over multiple boots however, I'd suggest running a memory test (which you should be able to do from the initial BIOS boot screen).

Answer (score 0):

I also saw the same logs "Clearing orphaned inodes" after restarting my laptop. And upon logging in, I could only see a blank screen.
I was able to log in to the recovery mode, so the problem was definitely in the Nvidia drivers used in the normal mode as the recovery mode uses the Nouveau drivers.

So, upon restart, drop into the root shell prompt (either via the GRUB menu or CTRL+ALT+Fn) (Fn can be F1 to F6) and run:

```bash
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

The above command will autoinstall the drivers suited to your machine and update them.
Then, verify it using:

```bash
nvidia-smi
```

And, run:

```bash
sudo reboot
```

Now, you'll be able to log back in properly to your desktop with updated drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer (@faucacius) is good but there is something more that you can try.

1. Check if nvidia driver works:

   nvidia-smi
2. If it gives you an error purge nvidia drivers:

   sudo apt purge nvidia* libnvidia*
3. Then you can try:

   sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
4. Then reboot:

   sudo reboot
5. After that reboot an try this:

   nvidia-smi

If it gives you some kind of table in a xterminal, it works.

Instead of step 3 you can try this:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-{version}
```

Source:
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/failed-to-initialize-nvml-driver-library-version-mismatch/190421/4

Answer (score 0):

Some important file was corrupted and cleaned by fsck. Given the inability to login, I think `/etc/shadow` is among the files lost.

Try booting into a live CD of any Linux, then mount Ubuntu's root device:

```
root# mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

If indeed `/etc/shadow` is lost, you should recreate the shadow file:

```
root# sed -E -e "s/^([^:]+).*/\1:*:::::::/" /mnt/etc/passwd > /mnt/etc/shadow
```

Afterwards, chroot into the broken Ubuntu installation, then reset your password.

```
root# chroot /mnt
(chroot) root# passwd admin
```

Other things might also be broken, so you are strongly advised to reinstall the core system through APT. If you can reboot succesfully into the installation, you can do that from there.

```
(reboot or chroot) root# apt-get reinstall \
  $(apt-cache depends --installed \
      ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-standard \
    | grep -E '(^[^[:space:]]|Depends:|Recommends:)' \
    | sed -E -e "s/[^:]+: //;s/.*:.*//")
```

If you cannot, you may need to chroot again. This time however, the chroot `/dev`, `/proc`, `/sys` etc. may have to be mounted with the right filesystems for APT to work. Some installation media, mostly of manual-installation distributions like Gentoo and Arch, provide `arch-chroot`; replace the `chroot` above with `arch-chroot` to set everything up while chrooting. If there is no `arch-chroot`, see [this quick instruction from Gentoo's installation guide](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Base#Mounting_the_necessary_filesystems).